# Select documents from one collection based on IDs stored in another in Meteor and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have three collections, Users (Meteor built-in), Movies, and Seen. A document in Seen consists of a movie ID (the movie's ID in the Movies collection) and a user ID (analogous), indicating that that user has seen that movie.

I want to get only those movies (documents) in the Movies collection which the current user has seen.

I know how to select the documents from Seen whose user IDs match the current user's ID. Do I make an array of the movie IDs from this row and then use Mongo's $in operator? What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

As you already mentioned, you can use the documents from the `Seen` collection whose `user` IDs match the current user's ID to make an array of movie IDs that you can then query with on the `Movies` collection. Something like the following:

```
var seen = Seen.find({ "userId": Meteor.userId() }).fetch(); // get Seen documents
var movieIds = seen.map(function (s){ return s.movieId; }); // get seen movie IDs list
var seenMovies = Movies.find({"_id": { "$in": movieIds }}).fetch(); // get the seen movies
console.log(JSON.stringify(seenMovies, null, 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got the basic approach right:

```
var seenIds = Seen.find({ userId: Meteor.userId() }).map(function(doc){return doc.movieId});
var seenMovies = Movies.find({_id: {$in: seenIds}});
```